# how to convert anything to a string / bytes object so it can be hashed

Tags: python-3.x, hash

I'm trying to make a function that can take an argument and return a unique, short expression of that data.

A hash.

There's a whole `hashlib` package for doing this, but `hashlib` only takes strings. I want to easily hash anything: `lists`, `functions`, `classes`, anything.

How can I either convert anything into a unique string representation so I can hash it, or better yet, directly hash anything?

I thought you might be able to get the `bytes()` representation of an object but this needs special encodings for whatever it's given, and whatnot. so I'm not sure if there's a solution there.

```
hash_any(thing):
    # convert thing to a string of it's unique byte data
    # return hashlib.sha256(byte_data_str)
```

How would you go about doing this?

Edit: I've found the correct vernacular to find what I'm looking for. This is what I mean:

[Alternative to python hash function for arbitrary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38009699/alternative-to-python-hash-function-for-arbitrary-objects)

[What is the quickest way to hash a large arbitrary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097064/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-hash-a-large-arbitrary-object)

[Create Hash for Arbitrary Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157835/create-hash-for-arbitrary-objects)

I'm sure on of these contains a solution I seek.

Comment: `str(variable)` works on any data type in python

Comment: @R10t-- Yes it does, and I thought about that first of all. but, correct me if I'm wrong, doesn't `str()` often optimize for printing/viewing an object? For example say the `thing` is a thousand row dataframe. if you `print(thing)` it prints the headers of the dataframe, then like ten rows, then `...` then the last ten rows. I assumed, that this is because `__str__` has been overwritten in Pandas DataFrames to have this functionality. But I want to make sure I hash all the data, not just the viewable stuff. So this is why I thought to get the bytes of the whole thing.

Comment: If you want an exact string representation for *any* object, then for most custom objects you need to write your own. Even a simple item such as a float might need to be represented in hex.

Comment: @Legit Stack Ahh you may be right. I'm not sure about the `str()` implementation in pandas. It is very possible that pandas overrides the `__str__` implementation to pretty print objects if they are too large. Although, all python primitives will print all of their data and not concatenate. You could enforce the parameter to be a primitive and ensure users send in something like `dataframe.data` instead of the dataframe

Comment: @usr2564301 what's weird to me is that the data representation is unique at some level of the hierarchy - why isn't that level of the hierarchy available to me?

Comment: _"the data representation is unique at some level of the hierarchy"_ But is that the sense of uniqueness you want? Specifically, should `my_hash(list(5))==my_hash(list(5))` be true or false? What about `my_hash(MyObject(5))==my_hash(MyObject(5))`

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter cool username. love it. So those should both be true. but if `str(MyObject('abc'))` returns `'a...c'` and `str(MyObject('axc'))` returns `'a...c'` well then I'm in trouble, I can't rely on `str`. At some point, those two objects are different because they have different data (a different pattern). That's the layer I'm looking to reference the literal pattern layer. I don't care what it looks like, I'm not going to rely on it for anything except its ability to differentiate between different patterns of data. I just want different data to produce different hashes, thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for now, not optimal or efficient, but its fine for what I need.

```
def string_this(thing):
    '''
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103855/how-to-convert-anything-to-a-
    string-bytes-object-so-it-can-be-hashed
    attempts to turn anything into a string that represents its underlying data
    most accurately such that it can be hashed.
    '''
    if isinstance(thing, str):
        return thing
    try:
        # objects like DataFrames
        return thing.to_json()
    except Exception:
        try:
            # other things without built in to_json serializable functions
            return json.dump(thing)
        except Exception:
            # hopefully its a python primative type
            return str(thing)
```